# CSS grid template columns - how does it work?

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm new to CSS Grid and trying to learn how it works. I've found a layout that I've been playing around with but I can't seem to figure out how to get the article to span the entire width of the footer/header. I've tried changing the grid-template-columns but and get pretty close to spanning it but not all the way.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px auto 0px;
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

header,
footer {
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
}

@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
  aside,
  article {
    grid-column: 1 / 4;
  }
}


/* Demo Specific Styles */

body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 56em;
  padding: 1em 0;
}

header,
aside,
article,
footer {
  background: #eaeaea;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 25vh;
}

header {
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <header>
    Header
  </header>

  <aside class="sidebar-left">
    Left Sidebar
  </aside>

  <article>
    Article
  </article>

  <footer>
    Footer
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't seem to figure out how to get the article to span the entire width of the footer/header.

You have created a 3-column grid:

```
grid-template-columns: 150px auto 0px
```

You've set the header and footer to span across all three columns:

```
header, footer {
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
}
```

However, the article has no such instruction. It simply expands across column two, because that's the default setting (i.e., `grid-column { 2 / auto }`).

Therefore, you need to tell the article to expand across the third column. Add this to your code:

```
article {
   grid-column: 2 / 4;
}
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px auto 0px;
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

header,
footer {
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
}


/* new */
article {
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
}

@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
  aside,
  article {
    grid-column: 1 / 4;
  }
}


/* Demo Specific Styles */
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 56em;
  padding: 1em 0;
}

header,
aside,
article,
footer {
  background: #eaeaea;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 25vh;
}

header {
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <header>Header</header>
  <aside class="sidebar-left">Left Sidebar</aside>
  <article>Article</article>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for breaking it down like that! Appreciate the help